# SQL: Query to get three timestamp consecutive and put in the columns

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp

Imagine we have the following table where 0 is a start time, and 1 is an end time of the same kind x process.

| way | time | kind |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 12:12.34 | x |
| 1 | 12:12.55 | x |
| 0 | 12:15.22 | x |
| 1 | 12:15.59 | x |
| 0 | 12:16.07 | x |
| 1 | 12:16.42 | x |

I would like get as result:

| kind | start | end | next_start |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x | 12:12.34 | 12:12.55 | 12:15.22 |
| x | 12:15.22 | 12:15.59 | 12:16.07 |
| x | 12:16.07 | 12:16.42 | (so on) |

In time order the first three events should be pone in start, end, next start column because following the way 0 = start, 1= end, and so on.

i did in this way but there is an error regarding next_start

```
SELECT kind, start, end, next_start 
FROM(
    SELECT kind, F.time as start, S.time as end, max(F.time) as next_start 
    from Table F
    INNER JOIN Table S
        ON F.kind = S.kind
    WHERE end>start
        AND next_start> end
    GROUP BY kind, start, end
)
order by next_start
```

Comment: @D-Shih sorry was oracle

Comment: This would be a lot easier if there were a keys to match each start and end together.

Comment: Also, what's up with an image of a stackoverflow post for the results? Posting images of technical information like sample data and results, instead of formatted text, is the fastest way I've seen here for a question to be downvoted and then closed or ignored.

Comment: i tried in all the way to format it, in the preview it was visible but not after post.
what should I do?

Comment: It looks good now.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn thank you for the help to formatting :) appreciated that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try to use `SUM` window function to get each start and end time grouping number, then use `MIN` and `MAX` aggregate function to get the start and end time.

Final, we can try to use `LEAD` window function to get `next_start` column.

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT kind,
       "start",
       "end",
       LEAD("start") OVER(ORDER BY "start") next_start
    FROM (
     SELECT kind,
           MIN("time") "start",
           MAX("time") "end"
    FROM (
        SELECT t1.*,
               SUM(CASE WHEN way = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(ORDER BY "time") grp
        FROM "Table" t1 
    ) t1
    GROUP BY kind,grp
) t1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/70cc1/15/0)**:

```
| KIND |                 start |                   end |            NEXT_START |
|------|-----------------------|-----------------------|-----------------------|
|    x | 2022-06-15 12:12:34.0 | 2022-06-15 12:12:55.0 | 2022-06-15 12:15:22.0 |
|    x | 2022-06-15 12:15:22.0 | 2022-06-15 12:15:59.0 | 2022-06-15 12:16:07.0 |
|    x | 2022-06-15 12:16:07.0 | 2022-06-15 12:16:42.0 |                (null) |
```

Comment: in case we need not the next_start but the previous_end, how should change the query?

Comment: We can try to use `LAG` window function http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/70cc1/16

Comment: could you please just add this change, on this way i have the 2 solution.